# Dependency on Future Callout result

Tags: apex, callout, apexrest

We have a class that contains different methods,one of the method uses @future(callout=true) attribute which  makes Callout to external site. The response obtained will be used to update the Salesforce database in another method. 
Since database update method depends on first future call to finish, how to make sure dependent methods are fired at right time?

Comment: Future methods are async operations. They have separate transaction so you can not track when they will be finish. Probably you can perform database operation in same future method if it is possible.

Comment: If we will do database update in same future method , there is a issue with code coverage (where every thing is cluttered under one void future method). In order to have right coverage need to divide the work between different methods.

Comment: you can divide it in seperate methods and call those methods from future. Only a future method can not be called from future method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the method call inside the future method:

```
@future(Callout=true)
public static void callout() {
    response = http.send(request);
    UtilsClass.updateMethod(response);
}
```

If you're using it on a VF page you can also try the [continuation class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Continuation.htm).

If neither of these work, than I don't believe you'll be able to accomplish your goal.